Redpanda SegFaults when Running on RHEL7
When I try to start a Redpanda container on my RHEL7 (7.9 Maipo) box with
docker run docker.redpanda.com/redpandadata/redpanda:v24.2.2

It fails immediately with the following error:
hwloc/linux: failed to find sysfs cpu topology directory, aborting linux discovery.
redpanda: /v/build/v_deps_build/seastar-prefix/src/seastar/src/core/resource.cc:683: resources seastar::resource::allocate(configuration &): Assertion `!remain' failed.
Aborting.
Backtrace:
  0xa250cb3
  0xa2a43ba
  /opt/redpanda/lib/libc.so.6+0x4070f
  /opt/redpanda/lib/libc.so.6+0x98143
  /opt/redpanda/lib/libc.so.6+0x4065d
  /opt/redpanda/lib/libc.so.6+0x28901
  /opt/redpanda/lib/libc.so.6+0x2881d
  /opt/redpanda/lib/libc.so.6+0x38976
  0xa315fab
  0xa266c9b
  0xa1269c1
  0xa125958
  0x32ae2b6
  0xa798469
  /opt/redpanda/lib/libc.so.6+0x2a087
  /opt/redpanda/lib/libc.so.6+0x2a14a
  0x32a6ae4
Segmentation fault.
Backtrace:
  0xa250cb3
  0xa2a432a
  /opt/redpanda/lib/libc.so.6+0x4070f
  /opt/redpanda/lib/libc.so.6+0x289a4
  /opt/redpanda/lib/libc.so.6+0x2881d
  /opt/redpanda/lib/libc.so.6+0x38976
  0xa315fab
  0xa266c9b
  0xa1269c1
  0xa125958
  0x32ae2b6
  0xa798469
  /opt/redpanda/lib/libc.so.6+0x2a087
  /opt/redpanda/lib/libc.so.6+0x2a14a
  0x32a6ae4

My Docker version is:
Client:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-88.git07f3374.el7.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.10.2
 Git commit:      07f3374/1.13.1
 Built:           Thu Dec  6 07:01:49 2018
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.13.1
 API version:     1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Package version: docker-1.13.1-88.git07f3374.el7.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.10.2
 Git commit:      07f3374/1.13.1
 Built:           Thu Dec  6 07:01:49 2018
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
 Experimental:    false

I can successfully run this command, with the same image, on my Windows 10 box (using Podman and WSL) so I'm not sure what the issue is here, or where to really start debugging. Any help would be appreciated.

RHEL7 is End Of Life.

Speaking with Redpanda support it sounds like this is an issue with RHEL7, their minimum supported version is 8
